# How to avoid conflicts when two tasks start at same time in c# while using aync await

Tags: multithreading, async-await, task

When we call async method in another async method,
sometimes few of tasks getting into conflict.

If two tasks of EventReceiverAsync running at same time. For example getData(1) and getData(2) run parallely.
If getData(2) response is faster than getData(1). In this case objPayload taking getData(2) response even
for the task1.
Sometimes there is chance of conflict happens.

```
private async Task EventReceiverAsync(ID)
{
Payload objPayload = await getData(ID);
}


 private async Task<Payload> getData(string ID)
        {
Payload objOutput= new Payload ();
objOutput = await CallAPI("/api/getapidata", ID);
return objOutput;
}
```

Is there any way to categorize output based on task through any Id or something?

Answer (score 0):

> For example getData(1) and getData(2) run parallely. If getData(2) response is faster than getData(1). In this case objPayload taking getData(2) response even for the task1.

This is not possible with the code you posted. There are two invocations of `EventReceiverAsync`, each with its own `objPayload` variable. The `objPayload` for task 1 will receive the result of `getData(1)`, and the `objPayload` for task 2 will receive the result of `getData(2)`, regardless of completion order.

As long as your code returns its results, mixing results will not happen. However, if your code sets some shared variable as its "result", then that sharing will have to be managed by you to avoid mixing up the results.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, Yes my code has some shared variable, and that's mixing up responses. I don't have way to categorize result based on task. Is there any way?

Comment: The better solution is to fix the shared variables.